# celery run task in future, keeps showing log statement

Tags: celery, django-celery

I have a celery task which I have set for 36 hours in the future. It says there's only one task, however, I see the following in my log almost every 20 seconds:

```
Got task from broker: celery_tasks.login_registration.followup_email[12d34c3e-7344-4867-9365-e594baec42f4] eta:[2013-06-24 11:50:43.984275+00:00]
Got task from broker: celery_tasks.login_registration.followup_email[12d34c3e-7344-4867-9365-e594baec42f4] eta:[2013-06-24 11:50:43.984275+00:00]
Got task from broker: celery_tasks.login_registration.followup_email[12d34c3e-7344-4867-9365-e594baec42f4] eta:[2013-06-24 11:50:43.984275+00:00]
```

It seems like it keeps getting the task from the broker again and again and again? Is this normal behavior?